# Last six months number in python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to obtain the last six months number in python as a list.
Let's say we are in March, I want to obtain:

```
>>> last_six_months
[2, 1, 12, 11, 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to just use modulus calculation on the month:

```
[(datetime.today().month - i - 1) % 12 + 1 for i in range(6)]
```

This includes the current month; use `range(1, 6)` if you want just the preceding 5 months.

Demo:

```
>>> [(datetime.today().month - i - 1) % 12 + 1 for i in range(6)]
[3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10]
```

The `(month - 1) % 12 + 1` pattern ensures that you always get a value between 1 and 12.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with a list comprehension this way:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_six_months = [(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=i)).month for i in range(30, 180, 30)]
```

Comment: This results in incorrect dates when today is March 31st, for example.